# Clean, name-based urls with class-based views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls, django-class-based-views, clean-urls

Is there a way to write a url that looks like this: **unitedstates.com/state/city** with a class-based view in django? The **State** view has a slug and has a state model. **City** would be the same. While I can generate **unitedstates.com/state** or **unitedstates.com/city**, I can not figure out how to get **unitedstates.com/state/city**.

The documentation is no help to me. I would just like to know out of curiosity. Any help or explanation offered would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. I'm giving you one example here.

Define your models:

```
class State(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class City(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
```

Define your view:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import City

class CityDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_object(self):
        city = City.objects.get(
            slug=self.kwargs.get('city'),
            state__slug=self.kwargs.get('state')
        )
        return city
```

And finally, add this to your urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import CityDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<state>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)/$', CityDetailView.as_view()),
]
```